# Justify that total running time for the addition algorithm is of the form $c_0+c_1n$

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

In my reference [Page 22, Algorithms by Sanjoy Dasgupta, Christos H. Papadimitriou, and Umesh V. Vazirani,](http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf) it says that

> given $x$ and $y$ are two numbers of $n$ bits long, then the sum of $x$ and $y$ is $n+1$ bits long, and assuming that each individual bit of this sum gets computed in a fixed amount of time, then the total running time for the addition algorithm is of the form $c_0+c_1n$, where $c_0$ and $c_1$ are some constants.

How the running time for obtaining $x+y$ is $c_0+c_1n$ ?

The example given in the reference is $x=53,y=35,x+y=88$, ie.,

[image: pic]

in this example what would be the values of $c_0,c_1$?

---

**My Understanding**

We can prove that the sum of three single digit numbers is at most $2$ digits. This shows that $x+y$ is $n+1$ digits, as each steps of the addition invloves at most adding three single digits numbers including the carry.

Additionally, looking at the addition algorithm, each single digit addition involves $2$ additions at most, and there are $n$ such operations, therefore total of $2n$.

Comment: Whether the implementation is done in hardware or software, the carry is preferably always added, even when zero (testing for zero adds overhead). So you can count $2$ additions every time (except at ends). In your understanding, the count is $2$ *at most*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the claim is wrong, as nothing is said about the time for addition of two bits and a possible carry. This time might depend on the particular bit values  and even not be the same for every bit.

Anyway, if we admit that the time does not depend on the numbers at all, it can only be a linear function of the number of bits if the computation is performed sequentially.

The total time is the time to add the two low order bits, then the time to compute the carry and add it to the sum of the next two bits, repeatedly, then the time for the last carry. Hence taking into account the limit cases,

$$t_1+(n-1)t_2+t_3$$

Comment: The text says: assuming that each individual bit of this sum gets computed in a fixed amount of time.

Comment: @SoorajS: then the time is exactly $(n+1)\,t$. Note that this somehow contradicts the notation $c_0+c_1n$.

Comment: If I take $t$ the time to add individual bits, and $t'$ the time to compute carry, then there are $2n$ additions of individual bits, and there are $n$ carries to find. So isn't it $2nt+nt'$?

Comment: @SoorajS: no, you reminded yourself "each individual bit of this sum gets computed in a fixed amount of time". There are $n+1$ bits, so $(n+1)\,t$.

Comment: Okay. So it is $(n+1)t=t+tn$, where $t$ is the fixed time to compute each individual bit of the $n+1$ bit sum $x+y$, and that is in the form of $c_0+c_1n$, is this what the book says ?

Comment: @SoorajS: of course. Though they say it in a clumsy way.

Comment: @SoorajS: every process that handles $n$ elements in constant time has complexity $c_0+c_1n$. The text was poorly written, so that one has to conclude $c_0=c_1$, which is not realistic.